# Textfile as a datasource for MailMerge in MS Word - how to insert manual linebreak instead of paragraph mark in field?

Tags: ms-word, newline, mailmerge

I have created a textfile as a datasource for a mailmerge in microsoft word. This is working great. Now, i have fields which contains multiline values. When I use this field in the template it creates a "hard" line break (paragraph mark). What does I have to insert into the textfile, that word will creating a "soft" line break (manual line break)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first:apologize for bad english grammar or vocabulary use.

- the way is working with {quote} in ms-word, for example {quote 11} is line break or {quote 12} is page break.
- to set it in your document, you should familiar with fields.

press `Ctrl+F9` to insert field and then insert "quote ##" (## is any number charchode) in it. then press `F9` to Enter and execute.

Answer (score 0):

0x0b (i.e. "Vertical Tab") is probably the only way to do it, but I would check that you don't get document corruption in the output.